# Questions about 2018 community ads

Tags: support, stackexchange

Is there a specific date for starting the community ads post for next year? I and my friend created a free LaTeX tool and were wondering if it is possible to post it there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a specific date for starting the community ads post for next year?

No specific date. It's just when the person in charge of it at SE has the time to do it.

Browsing the  tag [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) gives some idea when it usually happened. It started beginning of December but over the years drifted a bit. 
Last year it was only beginning of February that it was posted. If the trend continues it could be middle of February, but it might also be earlier (or still later).

> I and my friend created a free LaTeX tool and were wondering if it is possible to post it there ?

Yes, feel free to post it there. Mostly the ads should be relevant to this community. Yours certainly could fall under this. In the end, it'll just depend how the community votes on your ad.